# Pygame Class and __init__

Tags: python, initialization, pygame

I'm making a game with levels. Would this be the correct way to make a level in pygame with the methods below. Is there a better way to make it?

```
class Level():

    def __init__(self,lesson, word,letter):
        self.lesson = lesson
        if self.lesson == 1:
            self.word = 1
           self.letter = 'J'
        if self.lesson == 2:
           self.word = u'\u0430'
           self.letter = 'F'
        if self.lesson == 3:
           self.word =  u'\u0435'
           self.letter = "T"

   def text_printer(self):
        text_print = "This lesson's letter is "+ word +". Type the letter-" +letter 
        return text_print
```

EDIT: Added text_print and clarified

Would it make more sense to do it this way

```
Class Level():
    def __init__(self.lesson)
        self.lesson = lesson

   def word(lesson):
        if self.lesson == 1:
           word = "Jack"
           return Jack

   def letter(lesson):
       if self.lesson == 1:
           letter = 'j'
           return letter

   def text_printer(word,letter):
        text_print = "This lesson's letter is "+ word +". Type the letter-" +letter 
        return text_print
```

Comment: There's only one method there. Why are you passing in `word` and `letter` if you're using `lesson` to determine them?

Comment: @kindall, I am using word and letters to render later in other methods. Should I just __init__ lesson and then have a separate method to declare what word and letter are?

Comment: That's not what I'm objecting to. It doesn't appear you're using them. If you're not using them, don't pass them in. If you're passing them in, then use them. One or the other, not neither.

Comment: @kindall I think that was my question. So the second block of code is the better way of writing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but to try and at least steer you in the right direction, take a look at this code:

```
class Level():

    def __init__(self, lesson):

        options = (1, "j"), (u"\u0430", "F"), (u"\u0435", "T")

        self.lesson = lesson
        self.word, self.letter = options[lesson-1]

    def print_text(self):

        text = u"This lesson's letter is {0}. Type the letter {1}."
        print text.format(self.word, self.letter)

l = Level(2)
l.print_text()
```